# IT 140 text based game does not add items to inventory

Tags: python

I am having trouble picking up items in my text based game project for an Intro To Scripting course.

I expected it to pick up the item when I specify 'get item name' and then remove that item from the player room, instead it just prompts the user for a move and keeps the items in the rooms and does not add it to the inventory.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
rooms = {
    'Entryway': {'East': 'Living Room'},
    'Living Room': {'West': 'Entryway', 'North': 'Bedroom', 'South': 
                    'Kitchen', 'East': 'Theatre', 'item': 'Armor'},
    'Bedroom': {'East': 'Office', 'South': 'Living Room', 'item': 
                'Sword'},
    'Office': {'West': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Basement', 'item': 'Fire 
                Spell'},
    'Basement': {'North': 'Office', 'South': 'Theatre', 'item': 
                 'Potion'},
    'Theatre': {'North': 'Basement', 'West': 'Living Room', 'item': 
                'Resistance Bracelet'},
    'Kitchen': {'North': 'Living Room', 'East': 'Dining Room', 'item': 
                'Ice Spell'},
    'Dining Room': {'West': 'Kitchen'}
}

inventory = []
villain_room = 'Dining Room'


def moving_rooms(direction, player_room):
    global inventory
    global rooms

    if direction in rooms[player_room]:
        new_room = rooms[player_room][direction]
        print('You are in ', new_room)

        if 'item' in rooms[new_room]:
            item = rooms[new_room]['item']
            print('You found the ', item)
        return new_room
    else:
        print('Wrong Way! Try another direction.')
        return player_room


def show_instructions():
    print('Welcome to The Goblin Game, GG!')
    print('Collect all 6 items to defeat the goblin or he eats all your food!')
    print('Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West')
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")


def player_status():
    current_room = 'Entryway'
    print(f'You are in the ', current_room)
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
        print('There is an item: ', rooms[current_room]['item'])
    else:
        print('There is not an item in this room.')

    print(f'Inventory: {inventory}')


def main():
    show_instructions()
    print('-------------------')
    player_status()

    player_room = 'Entryway'

    while True:
        if len(inventory) == 6 and player_room == villain_room:
            print("GG! YOU WON!\n"
                  "Congrats!\n"
                  "You collected all items and defeated the goblin!\n"
                  "---------------------------------------------------")
            break
        if player_room == villain_room and len(inventory) < 6:
            print("YOU LOSE!\n"
                  "You couldn't defeat the goblin and he ate all your food....\n"
                  'Maybe if you had more items.')
            break

        move = input('What is your next move? ').lower()
        action, *params = move.split()

        print(f'Inventory: {inventory}')

        if action == 'go':
            direction = params[0].capitalize()
            if direction in rooms[player_room]:
                player_room = moving_rooms(direction, player_room)
            else:
                print('Wrong Way! Try another direction. (North, East, South, or West)')
        elif action == 'get':
            if len(params) == 0:
                print('I do not know that item, please try again.')
                if 'item' in rooms[player_room]:
                    room_item = rooms[player_room]['item']
                    if 'item' == room_item:
                        inventory.append(rooms[player_room]['item'])
                        del rooms[player_room]['item']
                        print(f'You picked up the {room_item}')
                        print(f'Inventory: {inventory}')
                    else:
                        print('That item is not in here. Try searching somewhere else.')
                else:
                    print('There is not an item in this room.')
        elif action == 'status':
            player_status()
        elif action == 'quit':
            break
```

Comment: Don't make us retype your code from an image.  Post your code as plain text.

Comment: I'm sorry, first time posting. I'll edit the original post!

Comment: When they type "get", you only have `if len(params) == 0` under that case.  There is no corresponding `else` statement to check if there was something in params.

Answer (score 0):

This block of code is the problem:

```
elif action == 'get':
    if len(params) == 0:
        print('I do not know that item, please try again.')
        if 'item' in rooms[player_room]:
            room_item = rooms[player_room]['item']
            if 'item' == room_item:
                inventory.append(rooms[player_room]['item'])
                del rooms[player_room]['item']
                print(f'You picked up the {room_item}')
                print(f'Inventory: {inventory}')
            else:
                print('That item is not in here. Try searching somewhere else.')
        else:
            print('There is not an item in this room.')
```

All of the processing is indented underneath the `if len(params) == 0` condition.  You do not have any processing at all if `params` actually did contain something.